# How is the Bluetooth connection by Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth

How is the Bluetooth connection by Visual Basic Dot Net readers and text sent by the Bluetooth and thank you

Comment: This question runs a risk of closing immediately as the question does not make sense nor is it related to programming. Can you please elaborate on what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I think it probably relates to programming. I *think* the question is: How do I open a bluetooth connection in VB.Net and read from it? But I don't know that for sure. (And for anyone possibly misreading that: Unless he's Italian, the OP speaks English a *heck* of a lot better than I speak *his* language. And even if he is, I still don't fancy my chances in a linguistic face-off.)

Comment: @T.J Crowder: Ok...no prob...going by what you think...I have added an answer below for an shared source component for bluetooth stack.... ??? Dunno if that's what he's looking for - what you think?

Comment: I agree it's difficult to understand, but shouldn't we try to help rather than just closing the question? I added a link to the C4F Dev Kit on CodePlex, which contains a Bluetooth control.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should check out 32feet.net's blue-tooth software stack which is an addon component [here](http://inthehand.co.uk/content/32feet.aspx). Maybe that is what you are looking for? It requires .NET v2 or better to use.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 2):

The Coding 4 Fun Developer Kit (available for download from http://www.codeplex.com/C4FDevKit ) contains a Bluetooth control that you can just drag and drop onto a Windows Form.

The Bluetooth control implements 3 profiles: Serial Port, File Transfer and Object Push; plus it provides Device Discovery and Service Discovery features.

The kit also contains other useful controls, it is free, and it is probably a lot easier to use than trying to write your own Bluetooth control.

Hope this helps.